# How do I take the Laplcian of a function involving complex conjugate?

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory, greens-function

Let $\mathbb{H}\subset\mathbb{C}$ be the upper-half plane and let
$$
G_0^\mathbb{H}(x,y) = \log\left|\frac{x-\overline{y}}{x-y}\right|,\text{ where }x,y\in\mathbb{H}
$$

How do I show that

1. $G_0^\mathbb{H}(x,\cdot)$ is harmonic is $\mathbb{H}\backslash\{x\}$, and
2. As a distribution, $\Delta G_0^\mathbb{H}(x,\cdot) = -2\pi\delta_x(\cdot)$?

In other words, how do I show that $G_0^\mathbb{H}(x,\cdot)$ is the Green's function of the $\Delta_y$? I can't directly take the derivative of $G_0^\mathbb{H}(x,y)$ w.r.t $y$ since it involves complex conjugate so I am not sure how to proceed....

Not sure if it matters, but the boundary condition here is zero.

Comment: "I can't directly take the derivative...since it involves complex conjugate" - sure you can, what is stopping you? Are you using the correct definition of $\Delta_y$?

Comment: My understanding is that, in general, $f(z)=\overline{z}$ is not differentiable. Am I mistaken?